Why does an `echo` with brackets `()` break the `if` statement?
The if statement in following code shouldn't trigger, but it does. If I change echo () to echo [], it works as intended. So apparently it has something to do with the brackets ().
  set a=1
  set b=2
  if "%a%" == "%b%" (
    echo foo()
    echo triggered
  )

output:
triggered


It messes with the if structure which has parenthese ")" on them:
if condition true (do this) else (do this)
But you can escape the parentheses on the echo with circumflex "^" to get the desired output.
echo foo(^)
@echo off

set a=1
set b=1

if not "%a%" == "%b%" (
  echo foo(^)
  echo triggered
) else ( 
  echo foo too(^)
)
pause

When the command interpreter encounters the ) character, it understands that it is closing the instructions for the condition it finds, regardless of true/false.
It is not necessary to escape the ( character, only the closing ^) character.

This surprises me. I would expect even a very primitive parser that doesn't take into account the context of the symbol (e.g. ignoring it if it's in an echo or comment), would not be led astray in my case because the brackets come in a balanced pair.
